# How to connect to PostgreSQL in Erlang using epgsql driver?

Tags: postgresql, erlang

I would like to access a PostgreSQL database in Erlang. I downloaded the [epgsql](https://github.com/wg/epgsql) driver, it was a few directories and files, but I don't understand how to use it.

How can I write an Erlang program and use the epgsql driver to access a PostgreSQL database?

I made a new folder and copied all files from `src/` in the driver and `pgsql.hrl` to my new folder. Then I created a simple test program:

```
-module(dbtest).
-export([dbquery/0]).

dbquery() ->
    {ok,C} = pgsql:connect("localhost", "postgres", "mypassword",
                                     [{database, "mydatabase"}]),
    {ok, Cols, Rows} = pgsql:equery(C, "select * from mytable").
```

Then I started erl and compiled the modules with `c(pgsql).` and `c(dbtest)`.
But then when I exeute `dbtest:dbquery().` I get this error:

```
** exception error: undefined function pgsql:connect/4
     in function  dbtest:dbquery/0
```

Any suggestions on how I can connect to a PostgreSQL database using Erlang?

Comment: Not a direct answer for you question, but - read about rebar. It's describes how to organize your application and their dependecies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rebar is a good tool to use but, I'm finding it's good to know how your project should be structured so you can tell what to do when things go wrong. Try organizing your project like this:

```
/deps/epqsql/
/src/dbtest.erl
/ebin
```

Then cd into `deps/epqsql` and run `make` to build the library.

Your `dbtest.erl` file should also explicitly reference the library, add this near the top:

```
-include_lib("deps/epgsql/include/pgsql.hrl").
```

You'll probably want to use a Makefile (or rebar) that compiles your code when you make changes but, try this to compile things right now: `erlc -I deps/epqsql/ebin -o ebin src/dbtest.erl`.

When testing, make sure your load paths are set correctly, try: `erl -pz deps/epqsql/ebin/ ebin/`. When the erl console loads up, try `dbtest:dbquery().` and see what happens!

I don't have Postgresql setup on my machine but, I was able to get more reasonable looking errors with this setup.

Comment: I am getting make: rebar: Command not found
make: *** [compile] Error 127. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485205/how-to-build-and-use-epgsql-erlang

Answer (score -4):

I recommend to use ejabber pgsql driver https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/pgsql/trunk/

Comment: How is this answer relevant?