# How to build and use epgsql (erlang)

Tags: postgresql, erlang, rebar

My erlang program directory structure is below:

```
src
   pgtest.erl
lib
   epgsql
   rebar
```

I downloaded the epgsql library from https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql
then tried to build it with `make` which gave me the below error:

```
make: rebar: Command not found
make: *** [compile] Error 127
```

So then I downloaded rebar from https://github.com/basho/rebar and build it. It was build successfully and gave me the message.

> Congratulations! You now have a self-contained script called "rebar"
>   in
>       your current working directory. Place this script anywhere in your path
>       and you can use rebar to build OTP-compliant apps.

So as per my understanding I copied the `rebar` script from the `rebar` directory to my `epgsql` directory and then tried to make again. However, I got the same error. I know I am doing it wrong, but not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the epgsql Makefile[1]  that is defining the command as just `rebar`. If it were defined as `./rebar` then it would work to put it in the same directory.  Since it's not, you'll need to put it somewhere in your `PATH`, as the output of rebar's make instructed.

Erlang projects that include rebar itself will generally specify `./rebar`, while those that don't will expect it in to be located somewhere in your PATH.

[1] https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql/blob/master/Makefile#L1